# [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[]: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axF87.png)

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f9qV.png)

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLyRj.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDPAr.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2hCU.png)

My code is migrated to angular standalone
I don't know what I am doing wrong. Do I have to import or provide HttpClient somewhere else or in my Login component? I tried to provide it in my component and then i get the same error message but it says that there is no provider for HttpHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since App Component is a standalone component, you can simply add the AppModule to the imports array of AppComponent.

```
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppModule]
  ...
})
export class App {
...
```

Also ensure that in the `provideHttpClient` you are giving this

```
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
});
```

Ensure you have loginService added to the providers of either `App Component` this might fix your issue!

Comment: I did all the changes and still getting the same error.

Comment: @SwapnilKashish could you check my updated answer?

Comment: I have tried it and it solveed my problem. Thank you very much!